# Cannot publish: Visual Studio 2015 Tools for Docker

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2015

I have [VS2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-vs.aspx) + [SP1](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx) + [Visual Studio 2015 Tools for Docker v0.9.1](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0f5b2caa-ea00-41c8-b8a2-058c7da0b3e4).

When I attempt to publish a console app, I get this error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApp, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
1>
1>  Build succeeded.
1>           0 Warning(s).
1>           0 Error(s).
1>
1>  Time elapsed 00:00:00.3872322
1>
2>------ Publish started: Project: ConsoleApp, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
Environment variables:
Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\extensions\microsoft\web tools\external;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\NativeBinaries\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Windows Azure Tools\Docker\;C:\Program Files\CollabNet\Subversion Client;C:\blp\API;C:\blp\API\dde;C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14;C:\Program Files (x86)\Enterprise Vault\EVClient\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Man\Electronic Trading;C:\Windows\SysWOW64\;C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Wbem;C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\RMF\RMFQL\Bin\Win32;C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\AdminStudio\6.0\ConflictSolver;C:\Program Files (x86)\TIBCO\TIBRV\BIN;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\svn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Application Virtualization Client;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GitExtensions\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Users\gravitas\.dnx\bin;C:\blp\DAPI;C:\blp\DAPI\DDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\extensions\microsoft\web tools\external\.git
C:\Users\gravitas\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1\bin\dnu.cmd publish "C:\Docker\ConsoleApp\src\ConsoleApp" --out "C:\Users\gravitas\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\ConsoleApp52" --configuration Release --runtime dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1 --quiet
Microsoft .NET Development Utility Clr-x86-1.0.0-rc1-16231
Copying to output path C:\Users\gravitas\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\ConsoleApp52
Time elapsed 00:00:00.3091962
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets(386,5): Error MSB4018: The "InvokePowerShell" task failed unexpectedly.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.InvokePowerShell.GetMSDeployPath()
   at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.InvokePowerShell.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()

2>Publish failed due to build errors. Check the error list for more details.
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

### What I have tried

I've tried everything I can think of over the past few hours, including many combinations of targets (x32 vs. x64, CORE vs. CLR, etc).

Answer (score 1):

I've come to a rather uncomfortable conclusion: **I do not think Microsoft really likes the free version of Docker.** They like the paid version of Docker (i.e. Azure Containers). I believe they are pulling the classic [vendor capture trick](http://www.digistan.org/text:rationale).

Proof? Visual Studio 2015 Tools For Docker:

- Does not work with Docker;
- Works fine with Azure Containers.

Conclusion:

- Don't be put off by how impossible it is to use Docker via `Visual Studio 2015 Tools for Docker`. It was never meant to give you access to anything but Azure. To avoid confusion, it should really have been called `Azure Tools for Visual Studio`.
- Docker is easy! Create your own Docker file manually and publish using the command line. It's only 3 lines of code to run any .NET project under Mono, far less than the 200-line Powershell-based monstrocity that Visual Studio offers.

Please let me know if you want me to publish a full solution on how to publish a .NET project to Docker/MONO.

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue. I want to use Bamboo server to build .NET project to Docker. Is there any trick?

Comment: Yes, would you please list all of your command here? I used MS tools but didn't work well. My web application is an asp.net application.